# mysql non alphabetical order ?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
id | businessName|  keywords
============================
 1      Adam         FOX
 2      FOX          bla bla bla
```

the user insert a string, I want to search this string in businessName and keywords columns.so I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `business` WHERE `businessName` LIKE '%str%' OR `keywords` LIKE '%str%'
```

my problem:

first I want to get the businesses where there names match the `str`, then get the businesses where there keywords match `str`.

i.e : the user enter the word `FOX`, mysql will return two businesses (adam and FOX), in this case I want the mysql to return at first FOX (because it's name match the `str`) then return Adam (because it's keywords match the `str`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order by a value that is generated based on the match:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM `business` 
WHERE 
  `businessName` LIKE '%str%' OR 
  `keywords` LIKE '%str%'
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN `businessName` LIKE '%str%' THEN
    0
  ELSE
    1
  END
```

The example above is quite generic, but the following should also work in MySQL, just order by the condition:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM `business` 
WHERE 
  `businessName` LIKE '%str%' OR 
  `keywords` LIKE '%str%'
ORDER BY
  `businessName` LIKE '%str%' DESC
```

You would need to add `DESC` in the order by, since a match (true) will be ranked higher than no match (false).